# AngularJS weird CORS issues depending on method calling POST

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

Quite simply! Why does this NOT work:

```
      $http.post(apiUrl + '/some/url/blah', {params: data, withCredentials: true})
      .then(function(result){
          //success!
      });
```

Yet this DOES!!

```
      $http({
          method: 'POST',
          withCredentials: true,
          url: apiUrl + '/some/url/blah',
          params: data
      })
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          //success!!
      });
```

I get a 401 unauthorized on the 1st example! second works like a charm..

Comment: `params: data` is for a GET, for POST you should use `data: data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the $http.post shorthand, the second parameter is the data.  Try this:

```
$http.post(apiUrl + '/some/url/blah', {}, {params: data, withCredentials: true})
  .then(function(result){
      //success!
  });
```